# ConfigureAwait and performance

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, async-await

1. `await MyMethnodAsync()` and `await MyMethnodAsync().ConfigureAwait(true)` are they the same from the point of view of program operation?
2. `ConfigureAwait(false)` always improves performance?
3. When does `ConfigureAwait(false)` improve performance?
4. When does `ConfigureAwait(true)` improve performance?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` isn't about performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's like saying `volatile` isn't about not seeing field updates (from other threads) in loops; technically true, but in reality there's a significant crossover in terms of side-effects

Comment: @MarcGravell I wanted to say `isn't a Turbo switch` but I realized few people would understand this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah, those happy days when I moved from an 8086 to an 80386 (can't remember whether it was SX or DX), and having to use the turbo switch to play some older games

Comment: ConfigureAwait() is a significant .NET pockmark, why it got a bool argument is hard to reverse engineer.  [The senior team member](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) had to admit that passing *true* accomplishes nothing.  Passing *false* is troublesome, especially so in a library method, it forces execution to a worker thread and that can give the caller a big headache.  Which *may* make it complete faster, no longer being bogged down by an overburdened GUI thread.  But typically only used as a hack to avoid deadlock, perf is not on the table.

Answer (score 5):

1. at time of writing, "yes, ish"; the "ish" there is because a: there's a small amount of additional code that needs to execute (explicitly storing your preference in a struct, etc), and b: `await MyMethnodAsync()` works for *any awaitable return value* of `MyMetnodAsync`, but `.ConfigureAwait` is only implemented (at least by default) on some specific (albeit very common) awaitable types; more things are awaitable than you might think; as an example, `await Task.Yield().ConfigureAwait(true);` does not compile for this reason; the "at time of writing" is because I live in hope that maybe someday there would be some kind of assembly/module-level default that worked with the compiler to automate the default, so for a library you could say, for example, `[module:ConfigureAwaitDefault(false)]` - but: that does not exist today (nor is it in any plan that I'm aware of)
2. no; if there's no sync-context, it won't make any functional difference - and in many cases (modern asp.net, console exes, service exes, for example) *there is no sync-context* (by default); and when there *is* a sync-context, it still isn't guaranteed to make any performance difference; that isn't the point, really; the real point is simply: "if there's a sync-context, do I *need* to use it? do I actively need *not* to use it? do I care whether I use it, and if so, should I prefer not to?"; for *library* code that doesn't have anything to do with UI etc, the answer to that should ***usually*** (not always) be "I should avoid it, even if there is one"; for *application* code, the safest answer is *usually* "if there's one, I should use it"
3. when a sync-context exists, and would impose some kind of throttle / bottleneck, perhaps due to serializing callbacks over a single worker loop (as is the case for winforms); or worse: where that sync-context could cause a deadlock scenario (I guess a deadlock is the ultimate in bad performance?)
4. in theory, it shouldn't have a performance impact in any direction, other than the trivial step of executing a value-task operation

Comment: Could you provide simple working examples for points 3 and 4?

Comment: @user20181727 let me do it in words, not code; you're writing a file-processing tool in winforms, and you want to do the work in the background, and you want to use async IO, i.e. `await stream.ReadAsync(...)` etc - then do complex processing on each line/batch/whatever; let's say you use `Task.Yield()` to get off the UI thread; now, if you *don't* use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, every time you `await` (on an incomplete result), you're going to get back on the UI thread, and do the complex processing on the UI thread, blocking the paint loop and making the UI unresponsive (1/2)

Comment: @user20181727 (2/2) but *with* `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, we stay on "wherever we ended up" (probably the thread-pool), and the UI remains responsive; that's about all I have time to explain right now; for 4: it is hard to give an example of something not making any difference

Comment: It says to use true for UI and false for eg library. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/should-i-use-configureawaittrue-configureawaitfalse-viswanathan?trk=pulse-article_more-articles_related-content-card

Comment: @user20181727 in this scenario using ConfigureAwait(true) is just the long-winded way of saying "do what you were already going to do"; the quicker way is to *add nothing at all*; but other than that, I think we're broadly in agreement